# not append from to DBF file with c#

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

I can't append txt delimited with tab to dbffile. vfpoledb is installed, this is my code:

```
string path = "C:\\OTA\\sdf";
string strCon = String.Format(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source={0};", path);

using (OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = cnx.CreateCommand();
    cnx.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = 
       @"EXECSCRIPT('USE CCD' + chr(13) + chr(10) + 'APPEND FROM ""C:\OTA\sdf\DETATXT.TXT"" DELIMITED WITH TAB')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // here is the error
    return "OK";
}
```

> error: Unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll
>   Additional Information: Feature is not available.

Comment: The error seems clear: you can't go with `EXECSCRIPT` command. Try to read all lines and add the records individually

Answer (score 0):

ExecScript DOES work with VFP OleDb and I have used in the past, based on Append type CSV.  It MIGHT be an issue with your formatting of the command and the extra quotes.  For grins, try formatting it this way.

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
@"EXECSCRIPT('
USE CCD
APPEND FROM [{0}] DELIMITED WITH TAB'", @"C:\OTA\sdf\DETATXT.TXT" );
```

Comment: cmd.ComandText = "EXECSCRIPT('USE CCD6615 APPEND FROM [C:\\OTA\\SDF\\DETATXT.TXT] DELIMITED WITH TAB')" 
but it doens't work. Say Additional Information: syntax error